# Is there a known algorithm for finding the largest sub-matrix with no zeros from a large covariance matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I am working with a [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) that is 15131x15131, and I want to generate a new covariance matrix from this one that doesn't have any zero values. I want the new matrix to be as large as possible. Is there a way to do this in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT: As pointed out by commenter Bitwise, my claim below is incorrect: a covariance matrix must be symmetric, and a solution to the balanced biclique problem will not in general correspond to a symmetric matrix. I'll leave this answer here in case it's still useful.]**

Finding a subset of rows and columns that yields a square matrix containing no zeros is equivalent to the **balanced biclique problem**: build a bipartite graph whose vertex set V consists of a vertex for each row and a vertex for each column, with an edge between two vertices if and only if the matrix entry at that row and column is nonzero.  Now the largest non-zero-containing submatrix corresponds to the largest biclique (bipartite subgraph in which every vertex in one part of the vertex partition is a neighbour of every vertex in the other part) in this graph.

Unfortunately, the first page of [this paper](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~vassilis/co/biclique.pdf) says that this problem has been proved NP-hard, meaning there are no efficient algorithms known for it.  But now that you know the problem name, you might be able to dig up heuristic solutions, or perhaps there are worst-case exponential-time exact algorithms that are nevertheless feasible for datasets of this size.

Comment: You ignored the fact that this is not a general matrix but a covariance matrix, which means for example that it is PSD (positive semidefinite).

Comment: @Bitwise: If "removing lines/columns is similar to removing variables" and will result in a covariance matrix as you say in your answer, then my approach will also work, because that's all it's doing too.

Comment: Except that you have to remove the same line and column each time. OP stated he want a submatrix that is a *covariance* matrix. Will your approach always result in a symmetric matrix?

Comment: @Bitwise: Good point, I missed that. In general my approach won't give you a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove all rows/columns that have zeros in them? That should still yield a covariance matrix. Since the matrix represents covariance between variables, removing lines/columns is similar to removing variables. The order is not important.

In python (numpy) you would do it like this:

```
valid=np.all(A>0,1)
A=A[:,valid][valid,:]
```

Note that this method may not yield the largest possible matrix without zeros, but it guarantees that you end up with a covariance matrix. It is not clear from your question if you want the resulting matrix to be a covariance matrix **over the same set of random variables** or not.

Comment: This will in general result in a matrix that is much smaller than necessary, because it deletes both the row and the column containing a 0 when it is only necessary to delete one of them. E.g. if a matrix contains only 2 zeros, and these are not on the same row or column, then your technique will delete 2 rows and 2 columns to give an (n-2)*(n-2) matrix, when it would suffice to delete the column containing one zero and the row containing the other to give an (n-1)*(n-1) matrix.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I did not claim my approach is optimal. I do claim my approach is feasible, fast, easy to implement, and results in a covariance matrix.

Comment: Fair enough. If you update your answer to say that this approach is suboptimal in general, I'll drop my -1.